# How can I override a typesafe config list value on the command line?

Tags: java, scala, config, typesafe

I have an `application.conf` file with a structure like the following:

```
poller {
  datacenters = []
}
```

I would like to override `"datacenters"` on the command line.

For other configuration keys whose values are simple types (strings, numbers) I can override using `-Dpath.to.config.value=<value>`, and this works fine.

However, I can't seem to find a way to do this for *list*s. In the example above, I tried to set `"datacenters"` to `["SJC", "IAD"]` like so: `-Dpoller.datacenters="['SJC', 'IAD']"`, but I get an exception that the key value is a string, not a list.

Is there a way to signal to the typesafe config library that this value is a list?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

An alternative syntax is implemented in version 1.0.1 for this:

```
-Dpoller.datacenters.0=SJC -Dpoller.datacenters.1=IAD
```

Comment: What if I need to put an empty List?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue some weeks ago, and finally dived into the source code to understand what's going on:

- This feature is not implemented, it's not possible to define a list using command line argument

Fixing it wouldn't be that hard, but someone need to take time to do it.