# override typesafe configuration list to empty on command line

Tags: java, scala, command-line, properties, typesafe-config

How can I override a list in typesafe configuration to **empty list**?

My error is

```
has type STRING rather than LIST
```

for experimenting with:

```
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dvalue-foo=''"
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dvalue-foo=[]"
```

[how can i override a typesafe config list value on the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202501/how-can-i-override-a-typesafe-config-list-value-on-the-command-line) only outlines how to set specific values

Comment: Apparently: https://github.com/lightbend/config/issues/380 it is not possible for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an mitigation but as [cant override Typesafe configuration on commmandline in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47737103/cant-override-typesafe-configuration-on-commmandline-in-spark/47742761#47742761) is working no longer required.

Also, it seems that this is currently unsupported behavior: https://github.com/lightbend/config/issues/380