# Excluding all files under src/main/resources

Tags: scala, package, sbt

I have read this great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20491789/2786156) about excluding resources from package:

```
mappings in (Compile, packageBin) ~= { _.filter(!_._1.getName.endsWith(".conf")) }
```

I also tried it and it worked fine, but the problem is that in my specific case there lots of different files in `src/main/resources` and it's tedious to exclude any of them like this.

Is it possible to exclude *all* files from `src/main/resources` without specifying their names/extensions/etc... ?

Comment: You can just change resource directory to something else, but why have these files there in the first place? If you need specific resources per use case, use different directories and add them to `resourcesDirectories` per use case.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok The problem I'm trying to solve is to keep resource to run project locally under `src/main/resources`, but remove them and allow ops to provide production-specific when deplying the app.

Comment: Then build tools is a wrong way of doing it - you should rather make it a documented application parameter. Either as something passes through args (see libraries like Scopt or Decline), or something overriden by environment variables (https://github.com/lightbend/config/blob/master/HOCON.md#substitution-fallback-to-environment-variables) or through command line config override (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202501/how-can-i-override-a-typesafe-config-list-value-on-the-command-line)

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok Packaging resources into jar does not like a good idea anyway.

Comment: Packaging resources into JAR is a standard practice.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok Any reason to package configuration files into jar? They are intended to be overriden anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215577/discussion-between-mateusz-kubuszok-and-some-name).